# How to switch between TTS languages by pressing a button in Android

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I am making a translator app which translates both English to Italian and Italian to English. When an English word is entered it is translated and TTS speaks out the translation in the native accent. So I enter "Cheese" and this is translated into Italian, so "Formaggio" is displayed and said in an Italian accent.

My issue is that the TTS engine is setup with a locale on initialization of the activity and I am struggling to change between Local languages at run-time. If I enter an English word it used the Italian Locale as desired, but if I then enter an Italian word it will continue to use the first used Locale language, Italian not British. This works the other way around too, entering Italian word first uses the British language but will not switch.

Is it possible to set a TTS objects language ready for instant use by pressing a button?

Here is my code simplified:

```
public class TranslateActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

        Locale locLanguage, locLanguage2;
        private TextToSpeech tts;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.translate);


            locLanguage = new Locale("gb_GB");
            locLanguage2 = new Locale("it_IT");

            engtoita = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.engtoitaButton);
            itatoeng = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itatoengButton);



    engtoita.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tts.setLanguage(locLanguage2);

                    class bgStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                            try {
                                phraseEntered = et.getText().toString();  
                                translatedText = translate(phraseEntered);

                                if(translatedText!="")
                                {
                                speakOut(translatedText);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                                z = "Sorry, there was an error.";
                                translatedText = z; 
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                }

            });


    itatoeng.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tts.setLanguage(locLanguage1);

                    class bgStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                            try {
                                phraseEntered = et.getText().toString();  
                                translatedText = translate(phraseEntered);

                                if(translatedText!="")
                                {
                                speakOut(translatedText);
                                }
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    z = "Sorry, there was an error.";
                                    translatedText = z; 
                                }


                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
            }

    @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {


                int result = tts.setLanguage(locLanguage);

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
                } else {

                }

            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        }

        private void speakOut(String text) {

            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                } else {
                    Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                    installTTSIntent
                            .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();
                    languages.add("ita"); 
                    installTTSIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(
                            TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR,
                            languages);
                    startActivity(installTTSIntent);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I hope this is enough to code to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. I have looked up how to set the language of a TTS object on the fly but cannot see any examples where this is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better late than never...

Your onActivityResult is overcomplicated.
Consider using this one:

```
@Override
protected final void onActivityResult
(
    final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data
)
{
    // If TTS Voice data doesn't exist, download it.
    if (requestCode == TTS_DATA_CHECK)
    {
        if (resultCode != Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
        {
            // Voice data doesn't exist
            final Intent tnt = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(tnt);
        }
    }
}
```

(You'll need to define this constant)

```
private static final int TTS_DATA_CHECK = 1;
```

To set a different language:

```
// Change language
tts.setLanguage(new Locale("en")); // or "it"
// Say it
tts.speak("All you need is Love!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

`Make sure your device isn't set to "Always use default settings"`, or the language change won't be applied.

Final note: As you guessed, my TTS object is called **tts**

Comment: Thank you very much! Late is much much better than never! Your code worked a charm! Appreciated!

Comment: hey I had the same problem and this code works fine inside the activity but it doesn't work inside fragment.

Comment: @BLΛCK How is it possible?! Maybe it's a matter of **visibility**?